# Add default view for Rails Controller

Tags: model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I currently have no index views (`app/views/mycontroller/index.html.erb`), but would like to specify a default view if the user just types in: `localhost:3000/mycontroller`

Very new to RoR.  My current `config/routes.rb`:

```
MyTestApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "team/thatguy"
  get "home/about"
  root :to => "home#about"
end
```

In my controller I've been playing around with redirects, but the desired solution is to only show the smaller uri `localhost:3000/mycontroller`.

app/controllers/home_controller.rb:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render "home/about"
  end

  def about
    @title = "My Title"
  end
end
```

Comment: Which template do you want to render when the user accesses `/mycontroller`?

Comment: I only have a single template.  This is a very basic, entirely static website with one contact form.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, assume you want to render a contact page when you access `localhost:3000/mycontroller`

What you want to do is:

1. Create a controller (C of MVC) with a contact action.

   `$ rails generate controller StaticPages contact`

   Excuting this code in your console creates some directories and files:

   - `static_pages_contoller.rb` with a contact action.
   - `static_pages` directory under the `app/views` directory with a view template called `contact.html.erb`

   and you may have `get 'static_pages/contact'` in your `config/routes.rb`
2. Modify your routes:

   - Now you have access to the contact template with: `localhost:3000/static_pages/contact`
   - So to change the path, add a line to the `routes.rb`: `match '/mycontroller', 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'`
   - Then you'll get your desired results.

I might be wrong, the whole process and details are here: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Comment: That unfortunately isn't working :(.  I'm looking through more of the tutorial now.  I know something has to happen in routes.rb...